# Javascript: Is there a way to check if an array contains at least one element from another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to test whether or not an array contains at least one element from another array?

```
let array1 = [`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`];
let array2 = [`c`];
```

Basically is there a way to determine if array2 has any of the elements from array1 in a single step. I realize I could check to see if array2 has `a` or `b` or `c` or `d` or `e`, but I'm curious if there is a method that helps me.

includes() only allows me to check for one value. some() would allow me to test if `c` is included in array1 but not test if any of the five elements from array1 are part of the array2.

Is there some way of using reduce() or filter()?

Comment: You can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) with `includes`.

Answer (score 4):

You could take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
const
    array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    array2 = ['c'],
    hasValue = array2.some(Set.prototype.has, new Set(array1));

console.log(hasValue);
```

Comment: `hasValue = (a, b) => a.some(Set.prototype.has, new Set(b))` to be more reusable and `hasEither = (a, b) => hasValue(a, b) || hasValue(b, a)` to check in both directions.